# node-sass-middleware not rendering using express

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I'm having an issue where node-sass-middleware is not rendering my css here is my middleware code:

```
  // adding the sass middleware
  app.use(sassMiddleware({
    /* Options */
    src: path.join(__dirname, "public/sass"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "public/css"),
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    prefix:  '/static/css'  // Where prefix is at <link rel="stylesheets" href="prefix/style.css"/>
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I get this on the console:

```
  source: ~\public\sass\style.scss
  dest: ~\public\css\style.css
  read: ~\public\css\style.css
```

But the css file is never rendered and the website doesn't receive the file.

Here is my dependency list from package.json for more info:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "~2.5.2",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.10.0"
  }
```

Edit, if i remove the prefix line i get:

```
  source: ~\public\sass\static\css\style.scss
  dest: ~\public\css\static\css\style.css
  read: ~\public\css\static\css\style.css
```

Edit Filetree:

```
│   index.js
│   package.json
│
├───public
│   ├───css
│   ├───img
│   │       background.jpg
│   │
│   ├───js
│   └───sass
│           captus.sass
│
├───routes
│       index.js
│
└───views
    │   main.ejs
    │
    └───partials
        └───main
            └───pages
                    about.ejs
                    home.ejs
```

Comment: Remove the prefix line

Comment: I get a strange result if i remove the prefix line, and it still doesn't work, see edit on main post

Comment: Could you edit once more and put your file tree?

Comment: done, please see edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to set transpilation mode to Transpile `*.sass` files,
add

```
// adding the sass middleware
app.use(sassMiddleware({
/* Options */
    src: path.join(__dirname, "public/sass"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "public/css"),
    debug: true,
    indentedSyntax: true,//add this to use SASS files
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    prefix:  '/static/css'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

renaming my sass file to scss fixed the issue.

Thanks to am11 here for giving me his own working example that eventually resulted in a fix: https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware/issues/70